# Display document file using Java stored in sql database as varbinary(max)

Tags: java, sql-server, database, arrays, document

I have stored document file and photo in sql db as varbinary(max). I was able to retrieve the photo by converting to byte array. But I'm struggling with the document file.

Heres my code for the photo. **(This works fine)**

```
try{

            int row = View_Table.getSelectedRow();
            String Table_click=(View_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            query = "SELECT Photo FROM tourClient where ClientID = '"+Table_click+"' ";
             PreparedStatement stm = db.getconn().prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
             if(rs.next()){


                 byte[]imagedata = rs.getBytes("Photo");

                 format = new ImageIcon(imagedata); 

                 imagelbl.setIcon(format);


             }


        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

I tried the same thing for the document file but it doesnt show any output.. Heres what I have done for document file.I'm struggling to continue from that point.

```
int row = View_Table.getSelectedRow();
            String Table_click=(View_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());

            query = "SELECT DocumentFile FROM tourClient WHERE ClientID = '"+Table_click+"' ";
             PreparedStatement stm = db.getconn().prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();
             if(rs.next()){


                byte[] fileBytes = rs.getBytes("DocumentFile");




             }
```

I linked the photo to a label. What should I do with the document?

Comment: What type of data is the "DocumentFile"?  Word, excel, pdf, plain text...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I have uploaded PDF and docx

Comment: Swing can't really display docx, but it can (to a some extent through the use of 3rd party libraries) display PDFs.  A better solution is to write the contents to a file and use [`Desktop.open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) to display it